# protractor - send spec/suite name as parameter

Tags: javascript, testing, command-line-arguments, protractor, test-suite

can I run protractor tests with spec or suite name as a parameter?
I'm currently running it with:

```
protractor myconf.js
```

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is the specific `--specs` command-line argument:

```
$ protractor --help
Usage: protractor [options] [configFile]
configFile defaults to protractor.conf.js
The [options] object will override values from the config file.
Options:
  --help                                             Print Protractor help menu                               
  --version                                          Print Protractor version         
...
  --specs                                            Comma-separated list of files to test
```

You would still need a config to be passed, but `--specs` would override the `specs` set in the configuration:

```
protractor myconf.js --specs=test/e2e/myspec.js
```

You can also use the [`--suite` command-line argument](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e7873093ada02ad6c9d6e190b7184775ab3686ce/docs/referenceConf.js#L87):

```
protractor myconf.js --suite=smoke
```

where `smoke` matches the configured suite name:

```
suites: {
  smoke: 'spec/smoketests/*.js',
  full: 'spec/*.js'
},
```

---

Alternatively, if you are using `jasmine2`, you can make use of the ["focused tests" feature](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) by temporarily changing `describe` to `fdescribe` and/or `it` to `fit`.

Comment: you're the greatest. I didn't think there is such option. thanks.

Comment: How come --suite is not mentioned when you type "protractor --help"? What else are they not telling us?

Comment: @IanT8 yeah, good finding, my understanding is that's because we are just setting/overriding the `suite` from the protractor config..you can override everything in the config this way from the command line.